# Does WWF provide BPEL integration?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, bpel

I've found a CTP for such integration from Microsoft,
but it seems it never was officially released and supported.

Also - Do you know a list of WWF to BPEL activities mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably we can not expect real WF-BPEL integration from Microsoft. Even the CTP that you found, is not an integration effort but rather an import/export tool. David Chappel's [post](http://www.davidchappell.com/blog/2007/02/windows-workflow-foundation-and-bpel.html) (and comments) indicates that we must not expect too much on this.

Comment: IMHO this is probably the case also. just wanted to verify if others share the same thoughts.